# Android app link tries to verify a random host and fails

Tags: android, applinks

I have added applinks to my app and have uploaded assetlinks.json file already to my domain. Using the App Link Support, clicking on Link and Verify gives me the following:
[image]

So far so good. Now when I install the app and filter IntentFilterIntentOp in Logcat, I am getting a completely random host being added to the list of my domains. The host name is `string` and I get the following error.
java.net.MalformedURLException: Input host is not valid.

My activity in android manifest looks like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".mainactivity.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/nav_host_main" />
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="my-url" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

My question is where is the domain `string` coming from?
The logcat filter for IntentFilterIntentOp looks like this:

```
Verifying IntentFilter. verificationId:89 scheme:"https" hosts:"my-url string" package:"my-package". [CONTEXT service_id=244 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.
I was trying to also include variables in deeplinks in the navigation component.

so my deeplink in the fragment looked like

```
    <fragment
    ...
        <deepLink
            android:id="@+id/deepLink6"
            app:uri="@string/deeplink_setpassword_verify_email" />
    </fragment>
```

This was the place where Android took it as a string. So I had to write actual URLs here.